# Apply PCA to new data in Scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to test existing machine learning model on new data in real time. But the model depends on [PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) decomposition. Is it possible to transform only new data to existing PCA dimensions without calling `fit_transform` on whole dataset + new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [incremental learning](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning)? It is not the same what you want, but note many ML algorithms can not learn incrementally (without seeing all the instances at once). Scikit-learn have estimators - `partial_fit()` methods. For example, in a case of PCA you can use [IncrementalPCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA.html) and `partial_fit()`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I decided to `fit_transform` training data periodically, and just `transform` testing set between the PCA updates.